# How to delete stubborn directory?

Tags: permissions, rm, chmod, dropbox

I'm having issues with dropbox so I'd like to uninstall and reinstall it. To do so I need to remove ~/.dropbox-dist but no matter what I do it won't budge. If I run `ls -l` I get:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 user user     4096 Nov 13  2014 .dropbox-dist
```

I have full permissions on the machine.

I have tried,

1. `sudo rm -rf ~/.dropbox-dist`
2. `rm -rvf ~/.dropbox-dist`
3. `sudo su`, `rm -rf /home/user/.dropbox-dist`
4. Removing from Nautilus
5. `chmod 777 ~/.dropbox-dist`

But the error is always the same, "Operation not permitted"

Comment: Check if you have some dropbox software run

Comment: Running top I don't see anything with the preface "dropbox", nor do I see anything in gnome-system-manager. So unless dropbox uses an alias I don't think anything is running

Comment: Try: `lsof | grep .dropbox-dist` and see if there are any results that way.

Comment: @SailorCire: I'm not sure what this does, but the output is :
bash      31734         user  cwd       DIR                8,6     4096  4227377 /home/user/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-2.10.52

Comment: `user` is currently in a directory called `/home/user/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-2.10.52 ` and is running `bash` with a process ID of `31734`. Tell `user` to `cd` out of that directory and then try removing it. If that doesn't work, find the process and kill it, but that might cause **very bad** side effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few things you could do here:

1. First check whether you have a Dropbox daemon running.
2. Check the attributes of the Dropbox folder using `lsattr` and if the folder is not editable, then change its attributes to editable using `chattr`.

#### UPDATE

As OP has reported in the comments, the `.dropbox-dist` folder contains `i` attribute which means the folder cannot be modified, deleted or renamed. Hence to change the attrubute, you should use `chattr`:

```
sudo  chattr =e .dropbox-dist
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Checking attributes I find it has the attributes: "----i--------e--"

Comment: That's good. Attribute `i` means it can not be modified. So, now you can change the attribute and remove the `i` using `chattr`, and the folder would be modifiable then. Use `chattr =e .dropbox-dist`.

Comment: This works, thanks for your response. I didn't even know attributes existed...

Comment: Thanks for finding the chattr. I was able to do `sudo chattr -R =e <stubborn file directory>` and then was able to get rid of the directory which otherwise wouldn't go away due to these (hidden) attributes.